# Calling SP from JPA repository

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to call a SP from a JpaRepository but still having some problems.

This is my code:

```
@Query(value = "EXEC MY_SP 'param1', 'param2', :container_id, :parent_id, :transaction_id, 'another_Id', :last_modification;", nativeQuery = true)
void callSp(
    @Param("container_id") String container_id,
    @Param("parent_id") String parent_id,
    @Param("transaction_id") String transaction_id,
    @Param("last_modification") LocalDateTime last_modification
);
```

This is how I am calling the method:

```
callSp(
    '123',
    '123',
    '123',
    <any LocalDateTime>
);
```

This is what I get:

> InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not locate named parameter [last_modification], expecting one of [transaction_id, parent_id, last_modification;, container_id]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [last_modification]

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of the String

Comment: @İsmailDurmaz that's the issue, thanks Ismail! :)